# Why does MacVim show `@` and blank space for long strings?

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

This drives me really insane...

Say I have a short line of text on line 32, and a very long string on line 33, say 10,000 characters long... if I have word-wrap on, it ONLY shows line 32 and stops there, and instead of displaying 33+ it just displays `@` in the first column and all the rest is whitespace.

I have to move the cursor all the way to the very bottom and then the entire string appears at once.

This is extremely jarring because if you 'overshoot' when scrolling, it immediately disappears again.

I want it to behave sanely... where nothing jumps in or out of the screen all at once. It should just flow along like normal with all the other line numbers, and always be visible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is not your question but…who has a 10k character line? It's hard to discuss _sanity_ with these terms. Anyway, this is not a "MacVim" behavior. It's just standard Vim handling of such lines.

Comment: I propose quite the contrary. You honestly.. truly.. believe that no 'sane' use-cases exist with such long lines in files? Have you never heard of massive json or text dumps? Or massive CSV's with tons of data in each cell........

Comment: Use cases, no I really don’t. Not for text editing. If I have to edit such a line first step would be to split it up to manageable size. By then, the long line rendering format is not even necessary or applicable.

Comment: I’m sorry that I made your brain hurt. It’s just my opinion. I’ll be silent now.

Comment: lol true dat. I found the answer, it is: `:set display+=lastline`

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tallboy flagged for abusive. Whilst I agree that there may be use cases involving long lines of text, that's no reason to start slinging insults that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @StunBrick I never insulted anyone. If anything, he was the one that insulted me by italicizing *sanity* as if my entire question is stupid. All I did was reply that I'm shocked, and didn't use any insults...

Comment: Being blunt isn't an insult, it's just the truth -- implying someone's question is *insane* instead of answering the question, purely based on opinion however.. could entirely be construed as insulting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was I needed to add this:

```
" show as much of long lines as possible
:set display+=lastline
```